# Send Python Output to File from C#

Tags: c#, python

I want to get the output and error messages after running a python script from **C#**. The output works, however if there's an error in the python script the output returns as `""` and I can't get the error. The error displays correctly if the python script is run from Windows shell.

As a workaround I'd like to output from the python script to a txt file and then read the text file in C#. The below works in shell to write for the file mylog.log.

`python c:\temp\text.py 2>&1 | tee -filePath mylog.log`

If I run the code below in C# no `mylog.log` file is created.

```
    public string RunFile(string fileName)
    {
        fileName = @"c:\temp\text.py 2>&1 | tee -filePath c:\temp\myLog.log";

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"python", fileName)
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WorkingDirectory = @"c:\temp"
        };
        p.Start();

        p.WaitForExit();
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: I'd imagine you would have to redirect StandardError too, not just StandardOutput.

Comment: I imagine this is because you are redirecting standard output to your C# application and it's not getting piped out to `tee`. So either write the file from C# code or don't redirect StandardOutput, but then you can't read the Standard Output of the Process that ran

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. I've just enabled redirect of the error and am reading the error in C#.

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"python", fileName)
        {
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WorkingDirectory = @"c:\temp"
        };
        p.Start();

        p.WaitForExit();
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```